# Are there any programmers who might find programmable heuristics useful?

Tags: bigdata

I would like to know if my recent work, which is essentially free to implement, has data applications.

More obvious applications include:

- Guessing questions.
- Logic / objectivity.
- Psychic prediction.
- Problem-solving.
- Finding core content of text based on title alone.
- A deduction that can be used for finding new theories of physics.

Etc.

GUESSING QUESTIONS
Performing some associations on the neutrals between an original term and it's opposite, and then posing the opposite and neutral as a question may be a general formula for the core questions of any given initial topic. For example, a child may want to know who they will be when they grow up (who they will be is opposite to them, and growing up is neutral to being grown up or being a child).

LOGIC / OBJECTIVITY
The formula AB:CD AND AD:CB using polar opposites opposed on the diagonal may be the first formula for objectivity, a metaphor for math, and extensible to n-dimensional typologies, and exponentially efficient (deductions equal in number to the square root of the number of categories in the case of mod 4 sets).

PSYCHIC PREDICTIONS
The most memorable method may be choosing the opposite of a thing or person's category, and the opposite of what concerns them at the time, and combining them. For example, a motorcyclist who is mostly about himself may be concerned about meeting someone, about someone else's motorcycle, or about losing their motorcycle. However, other formulas also exist.

PROBLEM-SOLVING
Finding the opposite of every term in the best definition of the problem in the same order as the original corresponding words will solve any paradox, and if the problem includes the word 'problem' and the solution includes the word 'solution' then it also solves any problem that actually is a problem. Care should be taken to know what the problem actually is before solving it.

FORMULA FOR CORE CONTENT
Title='[quality of X] [opposite of qualifier mentioned in core content]'.
Core Content='If you [X] qualifier [subject of X and qualifier] [opposite of X clarified]'.

FORMULA FOR FINDING NEW THEORIES OF PHYSICS
'X --> String Theory --> Space Time'. I have found this formula effective in reaching new theories of physics after studying intuitive physics and intuitive calculus. A string-theoretic concept such as singularity or superstrings is developed from an initial concept into a further theory.

Is any of this exciting for app designers or big data scientists in any way? If so, I will try to make the work more helpful for programmers in the future, perhaps by linking to sample code or suggesting more specific applications.

What I didn't want to mention is I have very little programming experience, just a little object-oriented coding experience, so applying these methods seems to be entirely on the shoulders of other programmers.

I am actually afraid the methods, as valuable as they are, will die. Of course, I want to prevent that.

For further information, see link: https://nathancoppedge.quora.com/Programmable-Heuristics

Comment: I have modified the question to make it less self-promotional.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It looks to me that your question needs a summary on what it is really about. "I have some work, does it have application?" is not helpful. Even the link does not link to a summary of any kind - the landing page is almost entirely legal and similar stuff. If you expect that people spend some time answering your question, it is fair that you write better, clearer question.

Comment: Your "method for Generating the Souls of Literature" or "finding core content of text based on title alone" sounds like [automatic summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization). I looked at [your examples](http://www.nathancoppedge.com/alexandria.html) and I got the impression that the algorithm is to fit the title to one of your templates of unclear provenance. As @NeilSlater says, you should read about NLP. Later on you write, _"I need to pee" could be the soul of "Reigns of Fire", since "Reigns of 
Fire" might follow from "I need to pee"._ Is this for real?

Comment: I didn't mean to sound impolite. The second method is not primary, and that is just the best example I could find at the time for part of the second case. At my Alexandria page the second method is listed after the library of souls, so it is not primary at all. This is all take-it-or-leave-it stuff that either can be improved or has already reached a significant level, particularly the first method. The example is not the issue so much as the effectiveness of the first method in arriving at summaries of entire books, IMO.

Comment: Why don't you walk us through an example: how would you summarize MLK's _I have a dream_ speech? I think you should not worry about data science; our discipline is scientific. Philosophy is for proto-scientific fields. Maybe you can help the [A.I. people](https://ai.stackexchange.com).

Comment: 'If you yourself are without dreams, this dreamless state opposes you and what you represent' seems to be a close match for the coherent meaning of the expression 'I have a dream'.

Comment: Adding the expression 'speech' makes it more complicated, as it might imply 'If you yourself do not dream without a speech, not hearing this voice, and the fact that this voice is not heard, speaks against you and what you represent'.

Comment: Believe it or not, the 'soul formula' produces unique results for just about anything. That's why it works as a formula for souls.

Answer (score 2):

The area of computer science this most closely relates to is [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). There is a large body of work and ongoing research in this area.

You have a few barriers to achieving interest in your ideas from people studying the subject:

- The methods as you present them, are not tightly defined or easy to comprehend.
- Where the methods are comprehensible, they appear to be a form of [expert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) which attempt to address questions about a piece of text. Expert systems are not new to NLP and are used in many text comprehension systems, but generally work at the level of text adventures, or in very limited domains (e.g. Amazon's Alexa might use such rules after analysing input, when deciding between playing some music that you requested or booking you a table at a local restaurant)
- Some of the terms you use in your heuristics (such as "opposite") are not well defined for all inputs, and could be the subject of a large piece of research in their own right. A computer programmer would likely halt and ask you to define how to extract "quality of X" from a piece of content, before they could apply your rule.
- Claims such as "FORMULA FOR FINDING NEW THEORIES OF PHYSICS" will not be well received by any research or academic community. Unless you have actually discovered, published and had verified a new formula for physics using your heuristics, you are most likely to receive negative attention for making such a claim. If you cannot defend this claim about the effectiveness of your methods *with proof*, I'd advise not making such a claim.

Probably you could have some of your rules encoded as an expert system (perhaps with some existing NLP analysis to help with identifying the loose concepts in your rule system), and they would generate output for a range of inputs. They might be interesting in some contexts e.g. these rules, or ones like them, might be useful topic generators for [chatbots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot). However, they don't appear to represent a novel approach to NLP, nor do they align well with open research topics in the subject.